# How to create and port Android RIL on to device?

Tags: android, porting, ril

I am unable to create RIL interface to expose some hidden methords to the api level. 

When Creating RIL from the android Source and then porting on to samsung device Replaces the IMEI no. from the phone.

Is there any other way around to access layer 2 data from the telephonic network?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any direct way to access L2 layer data. If your device has some qualcom specific chipset then please have a look in GOBI API.